# Intellij - How do I know why a certain jar is included in my project

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

I have a multiple module in a gradle project.
I have a certain jar-hell now problem and I want to know who is the one that brings it.
For instance - I have a log jar fw and I want to know if it comes through Guice or rxJava.

Do I have a smple way to iew it in intellij?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet ultimately would be to run [gradle dependencyInsight](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:dependency_insight) from the command line (along with gradle the [gradle dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies) command). I do not believe IDEA has a more direct way to show this information.